# How to get post data in codeigniter framework php rest api?

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, post

I am trying to create one restful api in `Codeigniter` framework. I need to pass some data to api through POST method so I am trying to retrieve the post data in api but I m getting it blank.

I am passing latitude and longitudes like

```
{
    "lat1" : "19.306506",
    "long1" : "72.848110",
    "lat2" : "19.288461",
    "long2" : "72.860041"
}
```

from postman.

And trying to retrieve it two ways

```
class distance_calculator extends REST_Controller
{
    function distance_calculator()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mdl_cart_web');
    }    
    function get_distance_post()
    {
        $lat1 = $this->input->post('lat1'); // 1st way    
        $long1 = $_POST['long1']; // 2nd way 
        $this->response($lat1.$long1, 200);
    }
}
```

Both aren't working, I got empty string in response.
I am a beginner with codeigniter please help. Thank you.

Comment: Both methods do not return anything?

Comment: no, got empty string in response. @Clemenz

Comment: I mean, both methods are missing an `return` statement. What you could try is: `die('Lat1: ' . $lat1 . ' long1: ' . $long1);` before  `$this->response($lat1.$long1, 200);` for debugging?

Comment: lat1:  long1:  returns blank @Clemenz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As googling a little bit i found the following:

try replacing your `get_distance_post()` method with the following

```
function get_distance_post()
{
    $response['lat1'] = $this->post('lat1');
    $respone['long1'] = $this->post('long1');
    $this->response($response, 200);
}
```

Does that work for you?

source: [Tutsplus](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814)